# Convert 32bit PNG file to 24bit PNG file

Tags: php, png, png-24

How to convert **32bit PNG** file to **24bit PNG** file using PHP.

btw I am using Codeigniter, and planning to host files at Dreamhost.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: probably, I am just reading http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_formats

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
exec('convert -depth 24 /path/to/old/image.png /path/to/new/image.png');
```

There is a PEAR package for ImageMagick, although making a system call also works if your hosting provider hasn't installed the PEAR package.

Comment: `system('convert -depth 24 order/41/4e8e99f15be6f/png-export.png order/41/4e8e99f15be6f/png-export-24.png');`, what is strange I get this error **FPDF error: 16-bit depth not supported: order/41/4e8e99f15be6f/png-export-24.png**

Comment: -depth 24 is not correct.  The depth refers to bits-per-sample, and you want 8 not 24.  The simplest way to request RGB888 from ImageMagick is "convert old.png png24:new.png"